# Will merging several files into one using command prompt from windows not affect the data inside those files?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, analysis

I'm trying to consolidate various rpt files into one so that I could do my data analysis quickly. The script I used through the windows cmd are as follows:

```
cd "d"\work files\colors\finished" 

copy *.rpt consolidated.rpt
```

Since I'm dealing with figures here, I'm wondering if my data on the consolidated rpt is still accurate considering that it had undergone through that cmd thing? Like for example in the case of formatted excel files (.xlsx), the data are destroyed once I used the code above.

Comment: what is the format of these 'rpt' files?

Comment: Hi Gregor. These are particularly plain text with various data within them.

Comment: it should work. see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69575

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I hope this will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`copy` command has two different behaviours, two different ways to use it.

The first one is used to copy files. This is the behaviour used when

- The source is only one file and the target is not indicated (current folder is the target by default), it is a folder path or is only one file.
- The source includes wildcards and the target is none (current folder) or a folder path

The second behaviour is used to combine multiple source files into one target file. This behaviour is used when

- The target is one file and the source is a list of files separated by a `+` sign
- The target is one file and the source includes wildcards

There is a big difference between the first and the second behaviour. By default

- for copy operations the files are considered as binary data
- for combination operations the files are considered to be ASCII.

In your case, as the command will be considered as a combination operation, the files will be considered ASCII and the resulting file will contain data from the source files up to the first `0x1A` character (or the end of the file if not `0x1A` is found)

To make it work and be sure no data is changed, you must indicate to the `copy` command that the operation must be binary

```dos
copy /b *.rpt consolidated.rpt
```

More information:

- Microsoft TechNet : Command-Line Reference : [COPY command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771997.aspx)

Comment: Thanks MC. Another question, what is binary data? I know ASCII a little cause I encountered it in one of my data analytics. Sorry I've got a lot of questions. I'm still a beginner. :) Thank you in advance. I guess I need to research for this on the internet.

Comment: Hi MC. I've compared the procedure with /b inserted in the command. However, the first approach renders half more data compared to your approach.

Comment: @FrancesOuanoPonce, What is the difference between sum of the the size of the files you are joining and the size of the target file?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to take out the first consolidated target file from the directory where I was processing the second approach. Actually, there were no difference between the first and second approach.

Comment: @FrancesOuanoPonce, for pure textual data it *should* not be any difference. I was just trying to point that it *could* be a difference depending on the data inside the files. The `/b` just ensures you will not have to worry about it.

Comment: yeah I got it. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: @FrancesOuanoPonce, you asked what binary data is... well... actually _every_ file type is binary; the only difference to text files is, that the computer interpretes the stored data as human-readable characters; the file extension `.txt` tells the computer to treat a file as a text file... text files contain binary codes that constitute line-breaks (there are even different codes), or some even contain an end-of-file code; (to be cont'd...)

Comment: (...continued) in merge mode (that is, multiple source files and one target file), the `copy` command understands such special codes as per default (or when `/A` is given), so it converts line-break codes to Windows-style codes, and it stops reading each file at an end-of-file code; such modifications are fine for text files, but for any other file type, they are terrible; stating `/B` tells `copy` to ignore all these special codes and to copy every file unedited; in non-merge mode (that is, one source file and one target file), the source file is _always_ copied to the destination unedited...

Answer (score 0):

Rather depends on the file format. If the files are just plain old text, then the data should be fine, but most binary data formats don't handle straight concatenation very well. The biggest problem I see, if the .rpt files are plain text, is that it will be difficult to tell where one ends and the next begins.

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for the response. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "it will be difficult to tell where one ends and the next begins". The files are actually plain text.